# Replace a short nonzero subsequences in a zero subsequence in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, syntax

I want to overwrite some values in DataFrame column. My column contains a bit mask, but I should leave only long continuous sequences. For example, I have 00010011100, result should be 00000011100.

I've tried to

```
df_norm['map'] = 0 if ((df_norm['map']==1) & (df_norm['map'].shift(periods=-1)==0) & (df_norm['map'].shift()==0)) else df_norm['map']
```

And got an error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-100-087984ed1e2a> in <module>()
----> 1 df_norm['map'] = 0 if ((df_norm['map']==1) & (df_norm['map'].shift(periods=-1)==0) & (df_norm['map'].shift()==0)) else df_norm['map']
      2 df_norm['difference'] = df_norm['map'] - df_norm['map'].shift()

/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in __nonzero__(self)
    915         raise ValueError("The truth value of a {0} is ambiguous. "
    916                          "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."
--> 917                          .format(self.__class__.__name__))
    918 
    919     __bool__ = __nonzero__

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

This way is for one nonzero value in a zero subsequence. It'll be good to change length of a nonzero subsequence. For example, lenght = 3, column is 0010011110111, result is 0000011110000. How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Use `apply()`:

```
df_norm['map'] = df_norm['map'].apply(lambda x: 0 if ((x==1) & (x.shift(periods=-1)==0) & (x.shift()==0)) else x)
```

Comment: I've tried this way. 
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-101-64d28ccff0b3> in <lambda>(x)
----> 1 df_norm['map'] = df_norm['map'].apply(lambda x: 0 if ((x==1) & (x.shift(periods=-1)==0) & (x.shift()==0)) else x)
    

AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'shift'

Comment: seems it should be groupby outside lambda for access values in window

Comment: Could you maybe share example data with desired output?

Comment: I simplified my task for cases then one value should be replaced. Column in dataframe 00010011100 -> 00000011100. Actual length is about 70000 (rows in dataframe)